# Spark job fails with "Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)" error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm encountering an issue while running a Spark job that processes data using Python. The job fails with the following error message:

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)`

I'm submitting a Python script (ratings-counter.py) to Spark using spark-submit. This error occurs consistently, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot or resolve it.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

lines = sc.textFile("D:/Data-Engineer/Courses/apache-spark/ml-100k/u.data")
ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])
result = ratings.countByValue()

sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
for key, value in sortedResults.items():
    print("%s %i" % (key, value))
```

I am trying to run spark locally on windows 11, and I have also setup JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_HOME environment variables properly.

Here are all the logs:

```
24/03/18 10:24:22 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:366)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:345)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1049)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2438)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 32 more
24/03/18 10:24:22 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Data-Engineer\Courses\apache-spark\ratings-counter.py", line 9, in <module>
    result = ratings.countByValue()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2662, in countByValue
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1924, in reduce
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1833, in collect
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (host.docker.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:366)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:345)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1049)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2438)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 32 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2856)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2792)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3060)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:989)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2463)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1049)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:366)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:345)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1049)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2438)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 32 more
```

Given the above information, I'm seeking guidance on how to diagnose and resolve the "Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)" error in my Spark job. Any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I tried to install the correct version of Java, i,e. Java 8.